# Why does the else not work correctly?

Tags: python

I am making a simple hangman game for a class.  The current program does every step of the drawings, even if the user gets a correct answer.

```
import turtle
import random
import sys

while True:
    list = ['report', 'beach', 'mayor', 'score', 'overeat', 'load', 'battery', 'social', 'honor', 'risk']

    turns = 10
    guesses = ''
    err = 0

    usedw = random.choice(list)

    wn = turtle.Screen()
    draw = turtle.Turtle()

    length = len(usedw)

    print("Welcome to hangman your word is", length, "letters long.")

    while turns > 0:
        guess = input("Choose a character: ")
        guesses += guess;
        lengthr = 0
        for char in usedw:
            if char in guesses:
                print (char,)
                lengthr += 1;
            else:
                err += 1;
                if err == 1:
                    draw.goto(0,0)
                    draw.down()
                    draw.goto(200,0)
                elif err == 2:
                    draw.up()
                    draw.goto(0,0)
                    draw.down()
                    draw.goto(0,200)
                elif err == 3:
                    draw.up()
                    draw.goto(0,200)
                    draw.down()
                    draw.goto(100,200)
                elif err == 4:
                    draw.up()
                    draw.goto(100,200)
                    draw.down()
                    draw.goto(100,150)
                elif err == 5:
                    draw.up()
                    draw.goto(100,100)
                    draw.down()
                    draw.circle(25)
                elif err == 6:
                    draw.up()
                    draw.goto(100,100)
                    draw.down()
                    draw.goto(100,50)
                elif err == 7:
                    draw.up()
                    draw.goto(75,90)
                    draw.down()
                    draw.goto(125,90)
                elif err == 8:
                    draw.up()
                    draw.goto(100,50)
                    draw.down()
                    draw.goto(75,35)
                elif err == 9:
                    draw.up()
                    draw.goto(100,50)
                    draw.down()
                    draw.goto(125,35)
                    print("You loose.")
                    break
            if lengthr == length:
                print ("You won!")
                break
        cont = input("Would you like to continue (y/n) ")
        if cont == 'y':
            print("Alright!")
        else:
            print("Thanks for playing!")
            break
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: You're dinging them once for each character they didn't guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import turtle
import random
import sys

while True:
    list = ['report', 'beach', 'mayor', 'score', 'overeat', 'load', 'battery', 'social', 'honor', 'risk']

    turns = 10
    guesses = set()
    err = 0

    usedw = random.choice(list)

    wn = turtle.Screen()
    draw = turtle.Turtle()

    length = len(usedw)
    p_length = 0
    c_length = 0

    print("Welcome to hangman your word is", length, "letters long.")

    while turns > 0:
        guess = input("Choose a character: ")
        # 'previous' guesses length
        p_length = len(guesses)
        # Adds unused guesses only
        guesses.add(guess)
        # 'current' guesses length
        c_length = len(guesses)
        # detect UNIQUE guess entry and guess in usedw
        if (p_length != c_length and guess in usedw):
            for char in usedw:
                if guess == char:
                    print (char,)
                    # decrement remaining chars to match
                    length -= 1
        else: # either a duplicate/unmatched guess
            err += 1
            if err == 1:
                draw.goto(0,0)
                draw.down()
                draw.goto(200,0)
            elif err == 2:
                draw.up()
                draw.goto(0,0)
                draw.down()
                draw.goto(0,200)
            elif err == 3:
                draw.up()
                draw.goto(0,200)
                draw.down()
                draw.goto(100,200)
            elif err == 4:
                draw.up()
                draw.goto(100,200)
                draw.down()
                draw.goto(100,150)
            elif err == 5:
                draw.up()
                draw.goto(100,100)
                draw.down()
                draw.circle(25)
            elif err == 6:
                draw.up()
                draw.goto(100,100)
                draw.down()
                draw.goto(100,50)
            elif err == 7:
                draw.up()
                draw.goto(75,90)
                draw.down()
                draw.goto(125,90)
            elif err == 8:
                draw.up()
                draw.goto(100,50)
                draw.down()
                draw.goto(75,35)
            elif err == 9:
                draw.up()
                draw.goto(100,50)
                draw.down()
                draw.goto(125,35)
                print("You loose.")
                break

        # detect completion
        if 0 == length:
            print ("You won!")
            break

    cont = input("Would you like to continue (y/n) ")
    if cont == 'y':
        print("Alright!")
    else:
        print("Thanks for playing!")
        break
        sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 2):

**THE PROBLEM**
 is in your in/correct determination logic:

```
for char in usedw:
    if char in guesses:
        print (char,)
        lengthr += 1;
    else:
        err += 1;
        if err == 1:
            ...
```

The **for** iterates through the characters of the word.  For instance, if the word is "overeat", you will execute this loop *seven* times for each guess.  Even if the player makes the best guess, "e", you will charge him/her with wrong guesses for the letters "ovrat", and draw five boy parts.

---

**REPAIR**

First, you have to determine whether the most recently guessed letter is in the word *anywhere*:

```
if guess in usedw:
    print (char,)
    lengthr += 1;
else:
    err += 1;
    if err == 1:
    ...
```

There are other problems and improvements, but this should get you moving.